# A strange step on a proof about the distribution of quadratic forms

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, quadratic-form

The following theorem comes from the 7th edition of "[Introduction to Mathematical Statistics](http://%5Cmu_x%20-%20%5CSigma_%7Bxy%7D%20%5CSigma_%7Byy%7D%5E%7B-1%7D%20(y%20-%20%5Cmu_y))" by Hogg, Craig and Mckean and it concerns the necessary and sufficient condition for the independence of two quadratic forms of normal variables.

This is a rather long extract but what I would appreciate some help with is only the transition from **9.9.6** to **9.9.7**. I have included the previous steps just to give the overall picture in case a previous result is implicitly used. Could you please help me understand then why **9.9.6** and **9.9.7** are equivalent representations? I have tried deriving **9.9.7** on my own but all my attempts ended in frustration.

The proof goes on after that but I do not have any other problems. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**(9.9.6)** states that$${\mathbf {AB}}=\{\mathbf{\Gamma_{11}'\Lambda_{11}}\}\mathbf{\Gamma_{11}\Gamma_{21}'}\{\mathbf{\Lambda_{22}\Gamma_{21}}\}={\mathbf U}\mathbf{\Gamma_{11}\Gamma_{21}'}{\mathbf V}$$Hence multiplying left and right by $\mathbf{U}'$ and $\mathbf{V}'$, we get
$$\mathbf{U}'{\mathbf {AB}}\mathbf{V}'=\mathbf{U}'{\mathbf U}\mathbf{\Gamma_{11}\Gamma_{21}'}{\mathbf V}\mathbf{V}'$$and
$$(\mathbf{U}'{\mathbf U})^{-1}\mathbf{U}'{\mathbf {AB}}\mathbf{V}'({\mathbf V}\mathbf{V}')^{-1}=\mathbf{\Gamma_{11}\Gamma_{21}'}$$I see no reason for the inner $\mathbf{U}'$ and $\mathbf{V}'$ to vanish so I would bet on a typo. However the conclusion remains the same, namely that $$\mathbf{\Gamma_{11}\Gamma_{21}'}=0$$ if and only if$$\mathbf{{AB}}=0$$

Comment: Yes that was my train of thought precisely, thank you. I looked at the list of the errata for this book but this is not on it so I found it extremely puzzling.

Answer (score 7):

I contacted the author Professor Joseph W. McKean who achknowledged the mistake and very kindly offered the correction. I am posting it here, in case anybody else studying on his or her own is in need of it.

---

**After (9.9.6) write:**

Let $\mathbf{U}$ denote the matrix in the first set of braces. Note that $\mathbf{U}$ has full column rank, so its
kernel is null; i.e., its kernel consists of the vector $\mathbf{0}$. Let $\mathbf{V}$ denote the matrix in the second
set of braces. Note that $\mathbf{V}$ has full row rank, hence the kernel of $\mathbf{V}^{\prime}$
is null.

For the proof then, suppose $\mathbf{AB}=\mathbf{0}$. Then

$$\mathbf{U}\left[\mathbf{\Gamma}_{11}\mathbf{\Gamma}_{21}^{\prime}\mathbf{V}\right]=\mathbf{0}$$

Because the kernel of $\mathbf{U}$ is null this implies that each column of the matrix in the brackets is $\mathbf{0}$. This implies that

$$\mathbf{V}^{\prime} \left[ \mathbf{\Gamma}_{21} \mathbf{\Gamma}_{11} \right]=\mathbf{0}$$

In the same way, because the kernel of $\mathbf{V}^{\prime}$ is null we have $\mathbf{\Gamma}_{11} \mathbf{\Gamma}_{21}^{\prime}=\mathbf{0}$. Hence by $\left(9.9.5 \right)$...

(and the proof continues for the other direction)

---